# How to get response from a url with two wildcard parameters?

Tags: php

I am trying to return html from a url that has two sections which need to have wildcards. I am pretty sure regex is the way to go (unless there are alternatives I am not aware of?)... but I can't seem to get it right. I don't have any knowledge of regex and was hoping someone could please help me with this.

The wildcards need to support any number of alphanumeric characters, including underscores and as many special characters as possible.

All of these are possible scenarios:

```
https://www.example.com/type/1062483_name
https://www.example.com/type/name_ii
https://www.example.com/type/name
```

I've tried using all the regex tools online but I can't seem to be able to match it. Here is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
$url = $baseurl . $type . $wildcard1 . $name . $wildcard2

function get_http_response_code($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
}
if(get_http_response_code($url) == "200"){
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
}
```

I need `(get_http_response_code($url) == "200")` to return true.

Any advice on how to make this work would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: The URL needs to be absolute, it cannot contain any wildcards. Besides what output would you expect from unknown number of websites?

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are used to find a broad match in a set of string(s), which is the opposite of what you are trying to do here. What you are asking for cannot be achieved: one way or another, you need a list of known wildcards to build the full url, or just a list of full urls to perform the http GET on them. If you don't have them, then this is a no-go.

Comment: Okay thank you guys. Found another way around it. Thanks for your help :)